# Using AbsoluteLayout for a background image but some elements are not correctly positioned Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an background image that I have to set to my ContentPage however the image is zoomed in. I need it to be at Aspect="Fill" so it appears properly. I looked online and the solution was to have either an AbsoluteLayout or RelativeLayout with an image. But when adding this, an image which is supposed to be at the bottom of the page is no longer there.

```
<RelativeLayout Parent="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Image Source="Background.jpg" Aspect="Fill" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"></Image>

    <StackLayout>

        <Label Text="Timetable" TextColor="Silver" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0, 10, 20, 0">
        </Label>

        <Image Margin="15, 20" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="350" Source="subtle-logo.png"></Image>

        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="PlayPauseButton" Source="play.png" WidthRequest="75">
        </Image>

        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="shareButton" Source="share-button.png" WidthRequest="50" 
               VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0, 0, 0, 20">
        </Image>

    </StackLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

However, that share button should be at the bottom of the page because of the VerticalOptions="End" property. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AbsoluteLayout` is better for performance reasons. Plus you are asking about `AbsoluteLayout`, but using `RelativeLayout` in the code you shared.

Regardless, you need the `VerticalOptions` for that last image to be `VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"` which will expand the area to fill the available space and then place the image at the vertical end of that area.

Basically the `Start`, `Center`, `End`, and `Fill` layout options say where to place the element in the available space or whether to enlarge the element to fill the available space, where `StartAndExpand`, `CenterAndExpand`, `EndAndExpand`, and `FillAndExpand` will expand the available space, if possible, and then set the item in that space to `Start`, `Center`, etc. `AndExpand` options are only applicable in a `StackLayout`

Here's the code if you want to use an `AbsoluteLayout` instead ([recommended by the Forms engineering team](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith%27s-xamarin-forms-performance-tips)):

```
<AbsoluteLayout>

    <Image Source="Background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

        <Label Text="Timetable" TextColor="Silver" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0, 10, 20, 0">
        </Label>

        <Image Margin="15, 20" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="350" Source="subtle-logo.png"></Image>

        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="PlayPauseButton" Source="play.png" WidthRequest="75">
        </Image>

        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="shareButton" Source="share-button.png" WidthRequest="50" 
               VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 0, 20">
        </Image>

    </StackLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```